# Open modal with images and selection on images in ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and use ionic modal. i want ionic modal with images and when click on images it will displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data to a modal using `componentProps`, something like this:

```
  async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: { 
        foo: 'hello',
        bar: 'world'
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

The `foo` and `bar` in the example above could be anything you wanted, like the url to an image you want to load, for example.

Inside the modal you can then use the passed data just by setting a public variable with the same name:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component()
export class ModalPage implements OnInit {
  foo;
  bar;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`${foo} ${bar}`)
  }
}

// hello world
```

So in your example if you passed a url into `foo` then you could set up an image with this markup inside the modal:

```
<ion-img [src]="foo"></ion-img>
```

A full tutorial is available at:

- [How to Pass Data to Modals in Ionic 4 | AngularFirebase](https://angularfirebase.com/snippets/use-componentprops-to-pass-data-to-modals-in-ionic-4/)

Comment: we can retrieve modal selected values using ngModel.